# Spatial join in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, spatial-query

I have three tables, one that's a polygon layer. One that has a begin date and ID :

```
Begin_Date                  ID
2015-12-14 00:00:00.0000000  1
2015-12-10 19:00:00.0000000  2
2015-12-09 19:00:00.0000000  3
2015-12-07 00:00:00.0000000  4
2015-12-06 00:00:00.0000000  5
```

And table with associated locations for those records based on the ID:

```
DateAndTime                 ID
2015-12-14 00:00:00.0000000  1
2015-12-15 19:00:00.0000000  1
2015-12-16 19:00:00.0000000  1
2015-12-12 00:00:00.0000000  2
2015-12-13 00:00:00.0000000  2
```

So far I have a query that selects the first point available. Next, I want to do a spatial join based on the point selection with the polygon layer. The result would show the id, first point and the polygon it falls within.

Desired result:

```
ID     point                          Area
35     POINT(-109.607635 40.876372)   TEST
```

Where I'm stuck:

```
    SELECT 
    t2.ID,
    ARRAY_AGG(ST_GeogPoint(Longitude, Latitude) ORDER BY t3.DateAndTime ASC LIMIT 1)[ORDINAL(1)] AS point,
    ST_GeogFromText(WKT) geo
    FROM `Table1` as t1, `Table2` t2
    INNER JOIN 
         `Table3` AS t3 
         ON t2.ID = t3.ID AND t3.DateAndTime >= t2.BeginDate
         AND ST_Within(ST_GeogPoint(t3.Longitude, t3.Latitude), ST_GeogFromText(t1.WKT))
    GROUP BY t2.ID;
```

A few things I'm not sure I'm doing right is that when I use the ST_Within function it's not using the points selected in the first part of the query. I also get a bug: unrecognized name t3 within the ST_within function. Do I need to have a nested select statement somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what's the input schemas are, so this is not a full query, but since you have a query that selects the first point working, just use it as subquery:

```sql
SELECT 
    ST_GeogFromText(WKT) geo,
    ...
FROM `Table1` as t1
JOIN (
    SELECT ST_GeogPoint(t3.Longitude, t3.Latitude) AS StartPoint, 
           ...
        <rest of the query that selects the first point>
    ) AS t4
ON ST_Within(t4.StartPoint, ST_GeogFromText(t1.WKT))
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks, that helped a lot.